# Conversion Issue when consuming soap web service

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, type-conversion

I have a web service that I have referenced called RemedyInc. I am attempting to consume this web service with the following c# code:

```
protected void ToRemedy_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RemedyInc.AuthenticationInfo AuthInfo = new RemedyInc.AuthenticationInfo();
        AuthInfo.userName = "user";
        AuthInfo.password = "password";

        RemedyInc.HelpDesk_Submit_ServiceRequest RemTicket = new RemedyInc.HelpDesk_Submit_ServiceRequest();
        RemedyInc.HelpDesk_Submit_ServiceResponse Response = new RemedyInc.HelpDesk_Submit_ServiceResponse();

        RemTicket.AuthenticationInfo = AuthInfo;

        RemTicket.Summary = "This is a web service Test";
        RemTicket.Last_Name = "Peck";
        RemTicket.First_Name = "Kenneth";
        RemTicket.Service_Type = RemedyInc.Service_TypeType.UserServiceRequest;
        RemTicket.Reported_Source = RemedyInc.Reported_SourceType.SelfService;
        RemTicket.Status = RemedyInc.StatusType.New;
        RemTicket.Urgency = RemedyInc.UrgencyType.Item4Low;
        RemTicket.Impact = RemedyInc.ImpactType.Item4MinorLocalized;
        RemTicket.Notes = "This is a web service test";
        RemTicket.TemplateID = "AGGAAHHLITMRAAMBGOJWBIN45LBV62";
        RemTicket.Action = "CREATE";

    }
```

Everything seems fine until I get to RemTicket.Status I'm simply selecting one of the options the web service provides but I get this conversion error.

> enum client RemedyInc.StatusType
>
> Error:
>   cannot implicitly convert type 'Client.RemedyInc.StatusType' to 'Client.RemedyInc.StatusType[]'

The web service is referenced as follows.

```
public string HelpDesk_Submit_Service(
                Client.RemedyInc.AuthenticationInfo AuthenticationInfo, 
                string Summary, 
                string Last_Name, 
                string First_Name, 
                System.Nullable<Service_TypeType> Service_Type,
                System.Nullable<Reported_SourceType> Reported_Source,                   
                StatusType[] Status,
                System.Nullable<UrgencyType>[] Urgency,
                System.Nullable<ImpactType>[] Impact, 
                string Notes, 
                string TemplateID,
                string Action) 
HelpDesk_Submit_Service(inValue);
return retVal.Incident_Number;
    }
```

RemTicket.Status is the type StatusType[]

```
        [System.ServiceModel.MessageBodyMemberAttribute(Namespace="urn:HPD_IncidentInterface_Create_WS", Order=32)]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("Status")]
    public StatusType[] Status;
```

How can I choose 'New' from the list provided by the web service and pass that to RemTicket.Status?

```
    public enum StatusType {

    New,

    Assigned,

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlEnumAttribute("In Progress")]
    InProgress,

    Pending,

    Resolved,

    Closed,

    Cancelled,
}
```

This should be simple but I can't seem to pass the correct 'Type' Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Status* is an array of *StatusType*

```
RemTicket.Status = new RemedyInc.StatusType[] { RemedyInc.StatusType.New };
```